# A list of the exponents of the irreducible factors in a factored polynomial

Tags: list-manipulation, polynomials

I have a list of factored polynomials:

`{x^3, x^2 (1 + x), x (1 + x)^2, x (1 + x + x^2), (1 + x) (1 + x + x^2), 1 + x^2 + x^3,  1 + x + x^3, (1 + x)^3}`

I want a corresponding list of the exponents of the irreducible factors. I want this:

```
{{3},{2,1},{1,2},{1,1},{1,1},{1},{1},{3}}
```

Comment: `In[314]:= Map[
 Rest[FactorList[#]][[All, 2]] &, {x^3, x^2 (1 + x), x (1 + x)^2, 
  x (1 + x + x^2), (1 + x) (1 + x + x^2), 1 + x^2 + x^3, 
  1 + x + x^3, (1 + x)^3}]

Out[314]= {{3}, {2, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1}, {1}, {3}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, define a function to get an exponent from a factor. If it's a `Power`, it's explicit, if it's a numeric quantity, it's `0`, otherwise it's `1`.

```
getExponent[Power[_, n_]] := n
getExponent[_?NumericQ] := 0
getExponent[_] := 1
```

Next, deconstruct a product into factors and map `getExponent` to the factors. Handle the special case where there's only one factor.

```
getExponents[product_Times] := getExponent /@ (product /. Times -> List)
getExponents[poly_] := {getExponent[poly]}
```

Finally, map it to a list of polynomials.

```
exponentList[polys_List] := getExponents /@ polys

exponentList[{x^3, x^2 (1 + x), x (1 + x)^2, x (1 + x + x^2), (1 + x) (1 + x + x^2), 1 + x^2 + x^3, 1 + x + x^3, (1 + x)^3}]
(* {{3}, {2, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1}, {1}, {3}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

As @DanielLichtblau comments, [FactorList](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FactorList.html) does this (and more):

```
L = {x^3, x^2 (1 + x), x (1 + x)^2, x (1 + x + x^2), (1 + x) (1 + x + x^2),
     1 + x^2 + x^3, 1 + x + x^3, (1 + x)^3};

FactorList[#][[2 ;;, 2]] & /@ L
(*    {{3}, {2, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}, {1}, {1}, {3}}    *)
```

According to [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FactorList.html),

> The first element of the list is always the overall numerical factor. It is {1,1} if there is no overall numerical factor.

which is the reason why we can simply chop off the first element (with [`Rest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rest.html) or [`2;;`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Span.html)).

Also, there is no need to pre-factorize the polynomials, as `FactorList` automatically factorizes:

```
FactorList[1 - x^2]
(*    {{-1, 1}, {-1 + x, 1}, {1 + x, 1}}    *)
```